# rabbitmq Emergency - how to save data when CPU is at 100% and the queue keeps growing

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have production rabbitmq running for a long time
The queues are simple. no routing or logic.

One of the queues got high number of entries (200K) and it caused the CPU to go 100%
now the queues became slow for extraction so they keep filling up quicker than they are emptied. 
Its a time bomb waiting to explode.

Please help - is there something I can do to save the data or open the CPU bottleneck?

RabbitMQ 3.6.1, Erlang 18.3
EC2 Instance.

File descriptors    Socket descriptors  Erlang processes    Memory  Disk space  Info    +/-
87
1024 available
37
829 available
552
262144 available
691MB
1.5GB high watermark
1.8GB
48MB low watermark
Disc 2 Stats

Number of connections is about 30

Please help

Comment: Stop your producers and let your consumers catch up. Then, when everything is stable again, upgrade RabbitMQ and Erlang. The versions you are using are very, very, very old.

Comment: connect more consumers to the queue in question here. Also, if there's any backup server you can shift the load to that one for time being until the majority of data is consumed. Make sure you have HA setup above rabbitmq to ensure no disruption of services